# In Drupal 7 how could I change style.css conditionally

Tags: 7, theming

Where in drupal themes files I could apply the following blueprint code:

```
if ($language->language == 'ar'){
// Do something to change the included style.css to be style_rtl.css
}
```

Does it template.php or html.tpl.php? and How to implement the comment in the code above?

I use Drupal 7

Answer (score 2):

You want to put it in template.php and probably want something like this:

```
function hook_css_alter(&$css) {
  global $language, $theme_path;
  if ($language->language == 'ar'){
    unset($css[$theme_path . '/css/style.css']);
    drupal_add_css($theme_path . '/css/style_rtl.css', array('group' => CSS_THEME, 'every_page' => TRUE));
  }
}
```

I think there is something in the [Domain Access](https://drupal.org/project/domain) project regarding theme settings, if you are using that suite of modules.

Comment: Your solution as it is, does not work. However, I had to replace the `hook` with the theme name to make it run. i.e `my_theme_css_alter()` Could you please tell me why does not it work with hook?

Comment: Because you create a hook implementation in Drupal by replacing `hook` with your module or theme name. I've edited the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be using prefixing your CSS classes/id's with .i18n-en and .i18n-es (for English and Spanish respectively). Here's an example:

```
.i18n-en .myclass {
    color: #ff0000;
}

.i18n-es .myclass {
    color: #336699;
}
```

You'll see this in the `<body>` tag.

You can also make use of hook_css_alter. Check this [page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_css_alter/7) for the official documentation and some examples.

Comment: Your solution is good but in the end will lead to very big CSS file that affect website performance (downloading time)